# What are the best stats to focus on for a warrior?

Tags: dark-souls

I have just started to play Dark Souls:  Prepare to Die Edition, and I picked the warrior class.  Due to the difficulty, I want to focus on some stats to ease the difficulty curve.

What stats do you suggest I should focus upon?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your starting class just determines the equipment and stats you start with, and so you are able to grow the character in any direction you wish. The most important thing to keep in mind when building your character is the following ([source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/32811/8350)):

> When it comes to developing your character, there is one thing you should keep in mind: **You should only boost one offensive stat**. This includes: Strength, Dexterity, Intelligence and Faith. The reason for this is that most weapons have stat scaling. So if you have a weapon which scales with strength, and you decided to split your points between dexterity and strength, all of the points invested in dexterity are essentially useless. That isn't to say you shouldn't put any points into the other offensive stats, just that you should only be putting enough to meet stat requirements for equipment.

If you've started as a Warrior then your best bet would be to focus on either a **Strength** or **Dexterity** build. This just boils to personal preference, since both are effective.

**Dexterity** based builds tend to focus more on mobility. The weapons available to Dex builds tend to be faster than those from a strength build, and Dex based characters can make effective use of bows (most bows scale good with Dex). However, most of the good shields have high Strength requirements so Dex characters will need to rely more on dodging to avoid being killed. The increased reliance on dodging also means you'll need to ensure your armour is light enough to not impair your movement.

**Strength** based builds tend to be more tanky. The weapons available to a strength build are usually slower compared to those used by dex builds, and strength based characters are able to make use of shields to block damage. Being able to wield a shield makes dodging less important, which also means you'll be able to wear heavier armour since decreased movement isn't as large of a concern. Strength based characters are unable to make effective use of bows though. If you do decide to make a strength based build I'd suggest looking at [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/53060/8350) answer where I go into more details on tank builds.

Some additional  details ([source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/35679/8350)):

> The key difference between Strength and Dexterity is the type of weapons you use. Strength favours weapons like Axes, long swords, and great swords; where as Dexterity favours spears, katanas, and curved swords.

Of the two stats, I personally suggest using Dexterity over Strength because ([source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/35679/8350)):

> Although all bows scale with strength, it is very low, whereas all bows have very high scaling with dexterity. Due to this you can easily dispatch enemies from a distance with your bow. I cannot emphasis how helpful this will be throughout the game. Not only does it let you dispatch enemies before they get to you, but also allows you to dispose of archers as soon as you see them, instead of being forced to dodge their arrows as you fight your way to them. Due to this, I highly recommended a dexterity build over a strength build.

Other stats you'll want to focus on are **Vitality** and **Endurance**.

Vitality increases your health, but after your invest 40 points into Vitality you start to suffering fairly severe diminishing returns, so I'd stop investing points once it hits 40.

Endurance increases your Stamina and Equip Load. Higher Stamina means you can dodge, attack, and block more often. Equip Load means you can wear heavier equipment before suffering from impaired movement. I wrote this on Endurance about tank build, and it applies equally well for Dex builds ([source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/53060/8350)):

> Similar to vitality, endurance becomes less useful after 40 points since stamina will stop increasing, and only your equip load will increase. I would suggest investing no more than 40 points into it because of this, but you will probably be able to get by only investing around 30 points.

Another stat you may want to invest points into is Faith, but only enough so you can make use of the [Heal](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/heal) miracle (12 points). It'll give you a little bit of extra healing, which can be really helpful.

Comment: warriors start with 13 dex. That is enough dex to use a short bow or composite bow and only 1 dex away from using a longbow. Enchanting the bow with lit/chaos removes the stat scaling. So a strength based warrior can use a bow pretty effectively with little or no dex investment.

Comment: @ColinD You'd still get more bang for your buck with dex scaling, but that is  a good point.

Answer (score 4):

The thing about Dark Souls is that the starting class does not matter aside from the initial alloted stat points and the gear you pick up in the "tutorial".

To answer your question "What stats do I need to survive more easily?" I would suggest Endurance, Vitality and Strength. This way you can (and should) equip a weapon that would normally need two hands in one hand and then have a shield in the other (thanks to the strength). On top of this you will be able to equip the heavy armours without too much of a penalty on your movement (thanks to endurance). Vitality speaks for itself, I'll leave the rest up to you since the best thing about Dark Souls is finding your own way through the madness.

Answer (score -1):

I just started playing dark souls and even though it is an old thread, I want to add on that investing on dex over strength helps increase the speed of casting spells which is a plus. Even if it is a warrior build, long (mid) range spells are super useful, seriously they make killing bosses such as moonlight butterfly and the gaping dragon, and mini-bosses such as titanite demon and tougher enemies like stone knights a walk in the park (if you can cast faster than they can hit you or you can just put more distance between you and them). So, I will recommend investing in some intelligence stats (to the point whereby the minimum requirements which is 12 to wield the basic spells - soul arrows, heavy soul arrows and fireballs are enough to get kill most things- are reached) and investing everything else in dex and endurance (with a few points here and there for vitality until it reaches ard 15-20). 15 is more than enough for vitality from early game all the way till more than mid-point of game, because if your endurance, dex and intelligence are high enough, you can dodge most attacks while wielding high damage dex weapons and if cannot be dodged, just attack long range with bows or spells. Since with high dex, your bows will have high enough damage and your spells can be cast fast enough to kill enemies before they reach you, and charging in as a warrior with dex + endurance build will give you great mobility, the enemies cannot even hit you to the point of using up your 15 stats vitality which is ard 698 if I remember correctly. So with good allocation in endurance + dex, one can breeze through the game all the way to more than 50% of game. Also, even if there are too many enemies overwhelming, just lead them through a narrow space and thrust at them with something like spear which mostly scale nicely with dex. If really must equip a shield, just use the hollow knight shield, super effective all the way up to mid-game. Because with this stats investment, the shield is only use to block last min melee attacks that can't be dodged or if there are too many enemies at one go. There should be little trouble dodging or running pass anything else. And if late game, other stats require investing, you will have more than enough souls to do so from killing the previous bosses, enemies etc. So, highly recommend a dex build over strength. (But have to invest in enough strength for any wielding requirements) Side note: spells are in my opinion better than bows because they don't take up stamina when used and aiming just requires a lock-on, no need waste time in zooming in etc. Plus, there is not really a need to increase in attunement as soul arrows + fireballs or better yet soul arrows + heavy soul arrows are enough to get you to most places. Bare maximum just need to increase the attunement stats by 4 for warrior to be able to equip an effective combination of spells (3 slots, no real need for anything more since is warrior build).

If want to have a strength build, you have to invest in strength (self-explanatory) + endurance (so that wielding heavy weapons/armour won't take too much load and stamina) + vitality (more likely not able to dodge out of way fast enough and just in case you run out of stamina, you can afford to lose health). Unless of course, your strength is so high (thus weapon damage is high) that you can kill most enemies in one swing. But this build will have higher trouble with bosses such as the stray demon because goodluck dodging their attacks, which damage most of your health in a single sweep, with heavy items equipped and landing the finishing blow before they do. Not saying is impossible just more difficult than the dex build. You will need high vitality + high endurance + high strength.

dex build: can have higher damage bows and quicker spells and greater mobility. + only need invest mainly in two stats which are dexterity and endurance. (for other stats only require bare minimum).

strength build: more likely can deal higher damage, just need use brute force to run through enemies (takes lesser time), not as effective against most bosses or tougher enemies though compare to dex build, such as with the hellkite + need to invest mainly in 3 stats compare to dex which only need 2 + dex build (which I suggested) give a more balanced stats overall compare to the strength build.

Everything is just my opinion though, so at the end of the day just invest in whichever stats you feel are worth investing.

Answer (score -1):

i actually think that a "quality build" would be the best. a quality build means that you invest in both strength and dexterity equally - 40 DEX and 40 Str, or 40 DEX and 27 STR if you plan on two handing your weapon because it is the softcap for two handing a weapon.
in a quality build you should focus on "quality weapons" that have good scaling in both DEX and STR, such as the claymore (C,C), zweihander (C,D) and so on.
the benefits of a quality build are that you deal much more damage (like STR builds) with **relatively** fast weapons (like DEX builds). on the other hand, since you must focus on two primary offensive stats (STR and DEX) you get less points for defensive stats (END and VIT).
i am running a soul level 125 build with a claymore and: 45 END, 45 VIT, 40 DEX, and 40 STR and it is super good.